# How to print a python function return value in shell?

Tags: python, shell

```
def hello():
    return "hello world"
```

The above is my python code. In the shell I am entering:

```
fooshell=$(python -c 'import hello; hello.hello()')
```

but when I do

```
echo $fooshell
```

I am getting an empty line.

Comment: This is really a shell question. The return value to the shell is a small integer, not a string. Meanwhile, the `$(foo)` construction doesn't get the return value of foo, it gets what foo printed to standard output. Once you understand that, the Python part is simple: print the string instead of returning it.

Comment: (PS, when you exit a Python instance with a non-integer value, I believe it logs the value to stderr and exits with 1. At least that's what `sys.exit` does. But that doesn't matter in this case, because you're not returning/exiting anything; you're just calling a function, throwing away its result, and falling off the end of the program.)

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Pretty much, the shell can only read from standard output.

Comment: Well, no, the shell can also read return values, it's just that reading return values and reading stdout are different things.

Comment: so if the shell can read return values, can't I store in a variable and then echo it to stdout? I understand it's inefficient but out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes (and it's not really inefficient—although it may be clumsy to write). For example, `python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(15)'; echo $?` will print out `15`. The most common thing you use return values for is as a boolean value (in the shell, 0 is true and everything else is false, unlike most programming languages), so `python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)' && echo success || echo fail` will print `fail`. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print`

```
fooshell=$(python -c 'import hello; print(hello.hello())')
```

If your `hello()` method itself doesn't print to `stdout`.